# Jboss 7 - Ignore global modules from war

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I have six applications in Jboss Instance jboss EAP 6.0.1
There is global  module defined as below.
standalone.xml

```
         <global-modules>
            <module name="oracle.jdbc" slot="main" />
            <module name="oracle.jdbc.ojdbc14_92" slot="main"/>
        </global-modules>
```

I want to ignore the global modules for one application.Is there any way to ignore this global modules for only one application and define the needed module inside the war file.
How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to the deployment and use an [exclusion](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile).

Example:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="oracle.jdbc"/>
            <module name="oracle.jdbc.ojdbc14_92"/>
        </exclusion>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```